# Why connection.hub.start() working but client.all.notify not working?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr

Why connection.hub.start() working but client.all.notify not working ?

my script

```
// signalr js code for start hub and send receive notification  
var notificationHub = $.connection.notificationHub;  
$.connection.hub.start().done(function () {  
    console.log('Notification hub started');  
});  
//signalr method for push server message to client  
notificationHub.client.notify = function (message) {  
    if (message && message.toLowerCase() == "added") {  
        updateNotificationCount();  
    }  
}
```

and

```
//Send Notification message to Client
var notificationHub = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<NotificationHub>();
notificationHub.Clients.All.notify("added");
```

code Startup.cs

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {

        app.MapSignalR();
    }
}
```

I dont get notifications unless I write alterdatabase query and run it along with insert query

```
insert into Contact(Name,Email,Phone,Message,SentDate,Sender) values (N'Test' ,'test@gmail.com','0123456', 'Hello World', GETDATE(), 'Admin')
ALTER DATABASE database SET ENABLE_BROKER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE ;
```

Comment: can you show your Startup.cs file?

Comment: I have updated the code in my post and I discovered something new

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I used jQuery version 3.5.1 and I changed it to 2.2.4 and it worked

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and realized that you have to add the client methods first and then start hub.
You just use this code:

```
var notificationHub = $.connection.notificationHub;

notificationHub.client.notify = function (message) {
    if (message && message.toLowerCase() == "added") {
        updateNotificationCount();
    }
}

$.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
    console.log('Notification hub started');
});
```